# How does a cookie match work if browser security restricts 1 domain from reading the cookie set by another domain?

Tags: cookies, dmp, cookie-matching

How are cookies matched between DSPs like DoubleClick and DMPs like BlueKai for the purpose of ad serving if browser security prevents 1 party from reading the cookie of another party?

From what I've read, the DSP ad pixel would piggyback on the DMPs container tag so that each time the DMP's pixel is called the DSP's pixel is called. At this point, what information can be passed from the DMP to the DSP that allows the DSP to equate its ViewerId to the DMPs ViewerId?

Perhaps, I'm misunderstanding how piggybacking works. Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Usually u will place a DMP container tag on the page (well, there are other ways as well, I only list one of the standard approaches), where the first request sent is to hit the DMP and the response is DMP id plus a bunch of redirects from the partners (DSP's pixel link could be one of them. Actually if u are using Bluekai,these seats are biddable through their data marketplace). Then the browser will hit all these redirects with the DMP id. So DSP knows the DMP id to its own id mapping. The responses of these redirects return each unique id of these partners, so DMP can store the mappings as well. A simplified explanination could be found at http://www.adopsinsider.com/online-ad-measurement-tracking/data-management-platforms/syncing-online-data-to-a-data-management-platform/

The param passed by http GET or POST is usually cookie ids, where the actual data syn is usually carried out through real time or more often batch download server to server communication.